# npm not found in Docker after working for previous commands

Tags: docker, npm

I don't understand why in the same dockerfile, the first two calls to `npm` work fine, but the third call fails, saying `npm: not found`

- npm config set strict-ssl false (on line 3 works)
- npm install -g http-server (on line 5 works)
- npm install (on line 14 **does not work**)

Error message

```
/bin/sh: npm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Here is the Docker file

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./app

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

Here is the full log file

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.8.0 (775dd39d)
  on docker Zr8WjzPx
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on baesvlodc146v...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
$ git config --global http.proxy $HTTP_PROXY; git config --global https.proxy $HTTPS_PROXY;
Fetching changes...
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Zr8WjzPx/0/microservices-and-cognitive-solutions/apps/ccn_bookings/ccn_bookings_gui/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 18e5c562 as development...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ npm config set strict-ssl false
$ docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:DEV .
Step 1/10 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> 90f281698f7a
Step 2/10 : RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
 ---> Running in ef08903f960c
Removing intermediate container ef08903f960c
 ---> cdca9c1e154c
Step 3/10 : RUN npm install -g http-server
 ---> Running in 7c2d617fb675
/usr/local/bin/http-server -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
/usr/local/bin/hs -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
+ http-server@0.12.3
added 30 packages from 40 contributors in 5.793s
Removing intermediate container 7c2d617fb675
 ---> 63281f9702bb
Step 4/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in bb23edc6c91a
Removing intermediate container bb23edc6c91a
 ---> 4fdf0a4bdd5a
Step 5/10 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> 4526a30eb736
Step 6/10 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 142a3ca29023
/bin/sh: npm: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 127
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: The only difference between the first two calls to `npm` and the third call to `npm` is that the `WORKDIR` has been changed. My suggestion is that `npm` is not on the `PATH` and must therefore be referenced by an absolute path. Or instead of copying the data to `/app`, we could copy them to the working directory directly.

Comment: I already tried using the absolute path and got the same error. I also tried copying to just `./` as well and no joy. The funny thing is, this is only happening on my VueJS app. I have node API Dockerized on the same computer, using the same stack and it works fine.

Comment: That works fine for me, up to a missing build script (because I just have that `Dockerfile` and the result of `npm init -y` in the directory).

Comment: Thanks for trying, this one has me stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the the problem and managed to get things working.

It seems that the problem was installing http-server globally, caused npm to no longer be available.

here is my working Dockerfile

Noticed I moved `RUN npm install -g http-server` to be the last command

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm config set strict-ssl false




# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server



EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```